# jQuery changing SELECT not working properly

Tags: jquery, select

(Using jquery Mobile)
I have a reset button that needs to reset all of the dropdown boxes selectedIndex equal to 0. I believe the index is back to zero, but the value shown on the select box is not correct. It keeps the same value.

Heres a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hZNje/)

For example: Select 'unit2' and then click reset. Click OK. The value shown on the select box is 'unit2' whereas it should say '--Units--'

HTML

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class='seltype' id='xmep' >
  <select id="dmep" data-mini='true'>
    <option value="0">--Units--</option>
    <option value='1'>unit1</option>
    <option value='0.01'>unit2</option>
    <option value='10'>unit3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

.

.

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#rstBtn').click(function() {
     var answer = confirm('Click OK to set the selectIndex equal to 0');

        if (answer == false) {
            return;
        } else {
            $('select').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
        }
  });

});
```

Comment: You don't need to grab the selected index...the value is 0, so....`$('select').val(0)`...and bam

Comment: @bagofmilk you need to refresh the `select`. Check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to refresh the select menu using `.selectmenu('refresh',true)`.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fhXb7/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#rstBtn').on('click', function() {
     if (confirm('Click OK to set the selectIndex equal to 0')) {
         $('#dmep').val(0).selectmenu('refresh',true);
         
     }
  });
});
```

This would be more precise

```
  $('#dmep').find('option[value="0"]')
  .prop('selected', true).addBack()
   .selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

or

```
   $('#dmep').prop('selectedIndex', 0)
   .selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

Comment: @bagofmilk Check my update, that is the more precise way to do it.

Comment: It took me hours to find this solution... thank you!

Answer (score 1):

in this way it works: http://jsfiddle.net/bWdGB/

Use this method for reset the selectbox:

```
$('select').val('0').attr('selected', true).siblings('option').removeAttr('selected');
$('select').selectmenu("refresh", true);
```